# Two web user controls are not working on a single web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, webusercontrol, web-user-controls

I used two web user controls on a single Web form. First web user control includes Grid View for displaying the headings in a vertical manner and second one includes a Data List for displaying headings in a horizontal manner.The two web user controls are in a single folder.The first one in working but the second one is not working.Here's the back end code for  Web user control 2 :-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;

public partial class WebUserControl2 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String st = Server.MapPath("XMLFile.xml");
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(st);
        DataList1.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal;
        DataList1.DataSource = ds;
     }
}
```

and the HTML code for web user control 2 : -

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="WebUserControl2.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebUserControl2" %>
    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="hl" Text='<%# Eval("txt") %>'  NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("url") %>' runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

I am using these two web user controls on a single web form.The second web user control is not working that I am using for displaying the headings in horizontal manner through Data List.Here's the HTML code for web form :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<%@ Register src="WebUserControl.ascx" tagname="WebUserControl" tagprefix="uc1" %>
<%@ Register src="WebUserControl2.ascx" tagname="WebUserControl2" tagprefix="uc2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <uc1:WebUserControl ID="WebUserControl1" runat="server" />
                <uc2:WebUserControl2 ID="WebUserControl21" runat="server" />
                <br />
                <br />
             </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to DataBind your [DataList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedatalist.datasource.aspx):

```
DataList1.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal;
DataList1.DataSource = ds;
DataList1.DataBind(); //add this
```